# How can I debug this Python syntax error with f string

Tags: python, syntax, f-string

```
def write_users_group(heading_writer, heading, user_writer, users):

    heading_writer.writerow([f"{heading}", f"{len(users)} users"])
    user_writer.writeheader()
    for user in users:
        user_writer.writerow(user)
    heading_writer.writerow([" "])
```

Error:

```
File "/Users/ashirwadniv/Downloads/gitlab/users.py", line 59

heading_writer.writerow([f"{heading}", f"{len(users)} users"])
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the code a [mcve].

Comment: It could be a problem on the line above - mismatched quotes perhaps.

Comment: Updated the code section

Comment: Could not reproduce with updated code. What version of python are you using? `import sys;print(sys.version)` would tell you.

Comment: I have Python 3.9.12 But with the code you gave above VS shows it as 2.7.18. 
Thanks for pin pointing, how can I solve this ?

Comment: It sounds like you have more than one python installed. This is happening in VSCode? I don't use that tool often so can't give direct help, but you could research how to reference the proper python in vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is only allowed for Python version 3.6 and above. Check/Upgrade your Python version.

Fyi, there is nothing wrong with your syntax provided the python version supports it.

Comment: My Python version is 3.9.12

Comment: Looks like sys.version says 2.7.18 so this is a question of using the correct installed python version in vscode.